# New android solution issue, MainActivity.cs not found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I tried to create an android solution using Xamarin studio but it always show me "MainActivity.cs not found!" error.I re-installed the software and the same issue appears. This error occurs when I try to create a new "Android application" Solution. After goggling it seems that my Xamarin.Android installation is not complete\corrupt but I am unable to get an installation link for it on the website.
can any one help me in this ?

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your issue?

Comment: Added picture of the same.

Comment: I dont understand the downvotes. We have similar issues on the stackoverflow website: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514303/monodevelop-android-error. Is this not a helpful question for the community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this to work by

1. uninstalling everything,
2. turning off antivirus,
3. running the "recommended" Xamarin installer as an administrator
4. restarting my PC.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you still searching for the solution.

This my understanding of cause and the solution.

Reason you are getting this error is because you do not have a correct right. You can see this by Xamarin Installation error exception - one of the parameter is privilege.

You need xamarin android installed to get this working!!

Xamarin is currently offering subscription and you are only have starter right.

search google "xamarin starter", go to the site down the xamarin installation again. follow the steps.

Once Xamarin Visual Studio got installed then this should be working..